# Search related range for number between 2 values (vba, Excel)

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm learning vba and I have an excel table which looks like this:

```
Range |max | min| discount%

R1    |0   |   9|         0                                                      
R2    |10  |  19|        10                   
R3    |20  | 100|        20
```

From another excel sheet, I have a field quantity purchased from which I want to retrieve the range coming from this table.

E.g

```
if qty = 6 then R1, if qty = 56 then R3
```

and so on

This is normally not so difficult with a vlookup when my table is static. My problem is the fact that the number of ranges can change (due to a macro I wrote). Here it's 3 ranges, but we can have more or less ranges with different values. Can someone please help?

Comment: Please post the code [that you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You can still use vlookup if you sort your lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to evaluate multiple things you can use "And" in VBA Its just like the excel version, both expressions must return true for you to receive a True answer.

This should get you going in the right direction,

Basic logic

a =  b  : a equals b

a <= b : a is less than or equal to b

a >= b : a greater than or equal to b

a <  b : a is less than b

a >  b : a is greater than b

a <> b : a is not equal to b

```
Sub ranger()

If Range("A1") > 1 And Range("A1") < 3 Then
MsgBox True
Else
MsgBox False
End If

End Sub
```

Put 2 in cell A1

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew it was simple but I think my mind was overloaded at the end of the day. I applied your code with some modifications to my vba. Thx;^)

Comment: Please mark complete if you're satisfied with the answer :)